# Thin running Redmine keeps crashing

Tags: ruby, redmine, thin

My redmine installation keeps "crashing" (stops responding to web requests) when it have run for some time (counted in hours).

It's installed on Windows 2003 R2 x64 and is proxied through Apache with reverse proxy.

DB is a local MySQL 5.5.

The CMD output is as follow:

```
D:\Applications\redmine>thin -p 4000 -e production -D start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Debugging ON
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4000, CTRL+C to stop
D:/Applications/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/fi
le_type.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant UnknownFileType
D:/Applications/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/fi
le_type.rb:126: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromExt
D:/Applications/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/fi
le_type.rb:132: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromShebang
D:/Applications/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/fi
le_type.rb:138: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromName
```

Ruby -v:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i386-mingw32]
```

gem q:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3, 2.3.9, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.2.3, 2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3, 2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activeresource (3.2.3, 2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.2.3, 2.3.9)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.3)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
coderay (1.0.6)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
journey (1.0.3)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.18)
multi_json (1.3.5)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
passenger (3.0.12)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prototype-rails (3.2.1)
puma (1.3.1)
rack (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3, 2.3.9, 2.3.5)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
rubygems-update (1.7.0)
sprockets (2.4.3, 2.1.3)
thin (1.3.1)
thor (0.15.2, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-service (0.7.2 x86-mingw32)
windows-api (0.4.1)
windows-pr (1.2.1)
```

I have provided what i think would be of interest to this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like crash has gone away.. I think i changed somthing about the threads, but i am not sure.

/ UniChaos

Comment: I had the same issue with not getting latest redmine 2.2 running with thin. I switched to puma and daemonized it with bluepill.